# Assign procedure to a variable

Tags: mysql

I want to select any random value i want using this procedure

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE randomdigit(troy INT)
     BEGIN
          select troy; 
     END$$
delimiter ;
```

To use it,i am calling `call randomdigit(n);`

However,when i try using assigning the procedure to a variable in a trigger i get this error

> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'call randomdigit(1);
>       SET the_class_id = (select examination_class_id from e' at line 11 */

This is my trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER lestrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON examinations
   FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE the_last_inserted_id INT ;
    DECLARE the_class_id INT;
    DECLARE the_year_id INT;
    DECLARE lesrandom INT;

    SET the_last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET lesrandom = call randomdigit(1);
    SET the_class_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);
    SET the_year_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);

insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id) VALUES (( select cs_id from class_students where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1 ),lesrandom);

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Is it correct to assign a procedure to a variable this way?.

Comment: Please use functions instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akhil's answer is a possible solution. In case you need a stored procedure, you have to work with `OUT` parameters.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE randomdigit(IN troy INT, OUT result INT)
     BEGIN
          set result = troy; 
     END$$
delimiter ;
```

and call it like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER lestrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON examinations
   FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE the_last_inserted_id INT ;
    DECLARE the_class_id INT;
    DECLARE the_year_id INT;
    DECLARE lesrandom INT;

    SET the_last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    call randomdigit(1, lesrandom);
    SET the_class_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);
    SET the_year_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);

insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id) VALUES (( select cs_id from class_students where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1 ),lesrandom);

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it as a function

```
delimiter $$
CREATE function randomdigit(troy INT) returns int
     BEGIN
          return troy; 
     END$$
delimiter ;
```

And change your trigger as follows

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER lestrigger
    AFTER INSERT ON examinations
   FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE the_last_inserted_id INT ;
    DECLARE the_class_id INT;
    DECLARE the_year_id INT;
    DECLARE lesrandom INT;

    SET the_last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET lesrandom = randomdigit(1);
    SET the_class_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);
    SET the_year_id = (select examination_class_id from examinations where examination_id = 1);

insert into examination_data (ed_cs_id,ed_examination_id) VALUES (( select cs_id from class_students where cs_class_id = 1 AND cs_year_id = 1 ),lesrandom);

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this is fine

Comment: I created a new function entirely `CREATE FUNCTION randstuff (s int)
   RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
   RETURN s;`